# How to create plugin list groups?

Tags: plugins, admin, dashboard, lists

How do I create more of these?
[image]

so that i can create proper plugins categories in the network plugin dashboard of wordpress.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

solved with the plugin: "plugin categories" .

Edited to explain how it works:

there are no hooks for the screenshot I posted, therefore the only solution is to offer a way to store categories relations into the database.

The plugin uses options table to store the data, ad saves through ajax.

Hooks into the columns display of the plugin page and offers an action link to edit the categories.

I added a bulk action to append categories to a group of plugins through default wordpress checkboxes.

To display only plugins belonging to different categories the plugin filters the view-all table eliminating the excluded ones.

Comment: This isn’t very helpful, because plugins come and go. Please explain how it works, so we can reproduce it later.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying some custom text there can be done using `views_plugins` filter:

```
add_filter('views_plugins', 'add_plugins_views', 10, 1);
function add_plugin_views($views) {
    $views['foo'] => 'bar (?)'; 
    return $views;
}
```

If what you need is actually setting a property for all plugins and display a count of this custom property you might want to take a look at [WP_Plugins_List_Table](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_plugins_list_table/).